# C# WebApi Json Posting

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have below C# code for WEB API When I post below JSON the Account object is always null. Please, anyone can guide on below code.

```
public class Account
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}

public object Post([FromBody] Account account)
{
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.status = "Status";
    return Request.CreateResponse(msg);
}
```

#### JSON

```
{
  "Accounts": {
    "id": "13456454",
    "number": "222",
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post just `{
    "id": "13456454",
    "number": "222",
  }`

Comment: Account object is null, because in JSON you specify `Accounts` field, and it doesn't exist in C# model. You should either use `{ "id": "13456454", "number": "222", }` as data you are POSTing or add extra model, that will contain that simpler model, with field named `Accounts` and type Account (not array of accounts, as name might suggest, because your JSON doesn't contain an array.

Comment: you you want get Account List

Answer (score 3):

Your json:

```
{
  "Accounts": {
    "id": "13456454",
    "number": "222",
  }
}
```

It can be parsed to object with property `Accounts` which has `id` and `number` properties

If you want to post only one `Account` your json should be:

```
{
    "id": "13456454",
    "number": "222"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to post **id** and **number** in following format:

```
 {
     "id": "13456454",
     "number": "222",  
 }
```

This will wok for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Account` object is null, because the C# code is inconsistent with JSON you provided. That's how MVC defends itself from badly formed requests.

Model suggests, that what you get in JSON are just these 2 pure fields, `id` and `number`, so JSON for it should look like this:

```
{
    "id": "13456454",
    "number": "222"
}
```

To make C# model adapted for provided JSON it should be built like this:

```
public class Accounts
{
    public Account Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

And API Action prototype should look like this:

```
public object Post([FromBody] Accounts account)
```

By this you contain `Account` into another class with property `Accounts` resembling what you have in provided JSON.

However your naming scheme suggest that single request might contain more than single account. To achieve this C# Classes should look like this:

```
public class Accounts
{
    public Account[] Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

And your JSON should contain object array:

```
{
    "Accounts": [
        {
            "id": "13456454",
            "number": "222",
        },
        {
            "id": "23456",
            "number": "125",
        },
    ]
}
```

Of course that array can contain only single element, if you need so, but it will allow you to put more than one `Account` at once, as your naming suggests.

For future reference, you should be more precise at what you want to be the result, to make sure we know best how we should help you.

Comment: Hi Buddy, I think is that a good syntax;   public Account Accounts { get; set; }

Comment: Well, that's what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending list of accounts from the client side but api is expecting a single object if you want to sent single object you can send single object from json file else you can change server object as List